# Shifting actual text inside textview in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Is there a way to set a padding or margin for the text INSIDE the textview?
For example I want my text to appear like this: [ text here ], rather than [text here].
I'm not talking about alignment or justification, just having the text not pressed up against the side of the textview.

I couldn't find a way to set any properties but would it be bad programming practice to just always place a " " in front of the text that's supposed to go in the textboxes?

Thanks

Comment: Textview background is transparent, why not let left and right margin?

Also, I don't think is a bad practice to use the white space if there is no other way of doing it, it's just a workaround...

Comment: @BogdanAndroid That's the thing, my backgrounds aren't transparent for this project haha. And okay sounds good, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does padding not work for you ?

XML:

To adjust the space between the text and the border of its textview you set the `android:padding=""`
property in your xml-file like this :

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ID"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="16dp"/>
```

You can also set a different padding for every side of the text with

```
android:paddingTop=""
android:paddingBottom=""
android:paddingLeft=""
android:paddingRight=""
```

Programmatically:

You can also apply padding programmatically by calling `view.setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

```
private TextView mTv = findViewById(R.id.Tv);

//calculate pixel to dp
int padding_in_dp = 16;
final float SCALE = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
padding_in_dp = (int)(padding_in_dp * scale);

//apply padding to view
mTv.setPadding(padding_in_dp, padding_in_dp, padding_in_dp, padding_in_dp);
```

Comment: Oh it may be because I was trying to do it programmatically, textView.setPadding wasn't working for me

Comment: I added setting padding programmatically in dp. This code works 100%. Maybe you just didn't see the padding because you applied it in pixel and not in dp. Please see my edited answer!

Comment: Oh interesting it does work.. I don't know why I didn't notice before, I guess I only used small values + I'm tired lol, thanks!